# Pandas Combine Same value rows and split different value columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have following dataframe:

```
ID  Year   Month   count 
1   2017    8       20   
2   2018    8       16   
3   2017    8       4
1   2018    8       109
3   2018    8       4
```

I am trying to get output in following format:

```
ID  Year_2017  Year_2018   Month    
1     20           109       8       
2     16                     8
3     4             4        8
```

Not:- Basically I want to split column `Year` and `Count` on distinct `ID`

Answer (score 1):

The point is to divide it up by the terms of the year and combine it with the ID. The rest is column names and removing unnecessary columns.

```
df2017 = df[df['Year'] == 2017]
df2018 = df[df['Year'] == 2018]
new = df2018.merge(df2017, on='ID', how='outer')
new.columns = ['ID', 'tmp_x', 'Month', 'Year_2018', 'tmp_y', 'tmp_month', 'Year_2017']
new.drop(['tmp_x','tmp_y','tmp_month'], axis=1, inplace=True)
new = new[['ID', 'Year_2017', 'Year_2018','Month', ]]
new.sort_values('ID', ascending=True, inplace=True)
new

ID  Year_2017   Year_2018   Month
1   1   20.0    109 8
0   2   NaN 16  8
2   3   4.0 4   8
```